# East Frisian term for “little wifey”

Tags: colloquial, phrase-request, northern-german

I am looking for an East Frisian German term of endearment, [epithet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epithet), or nickname meaning “little wifey”. My Grandmother came from there and used to call me with this term, but I can’t find the proper spelling.

It sounded like *leaveuh veefuh, liva vifa,* or *levah veefa.* It had nothing to do with *Frau.*

Answer (score 8):

This answer is based on several clarifying comments that have been posted on the question. However, the answer still remains speculative since we cannot know the actual expression that was used by your grandmother.

The substantive that starts with [v] and means *(little) woman* or *wife* could be:

- ***dat Wicht*** (German: *das Mädchen*; English: *the girl*),
- ***dat Wiev*** (German: *das Weib*, English, literally: *the wife*, more likely *the woman*),
- or the diminutive ***dat Wievke*** (German: *das Weibchen*, English: *the female*, in archaic words: *the wifie* or *the little wife/woman*).

By way of comparison, the usual translation of *woman* or *wife* would be *de Froo* (German: *die Frau*).

Considering that the pronunciation of the concerned word is described as “veefuh”, “vifa”, or “veefa” (with two syllables), the diminutive *Wievke* seems to be the likely candidate.

This word also appears in other cute expressions such as *dat Seewievke* (English: *the mermaid*) and *dat nakend(e) Wievke* or *dat witt(e) Wievke* (English: *the snowdrop* [flower]).

The adjective that starts with [l] and that sounds roughly similar to the above-mentioned substantive (also with two syllables) could be:

- ***lüttjet*** (German: *klein*; English: *little*), e.g. ***lüttje Wicht*** (English: *little girl*), or
- ***leev*** (German: *lieb*; English: *kind, nice, sweet, good, likeable, lovable,* or *dear* [the word is related to English *love*]), e.g. ***leve Wievke*** (English: *dear (little) woman*).

(Note that the neuter singular adjective ending is sometimes omitted; e.g. *lütt Wicht*.)

The sought-after expression should mean *little wifie;* however, the considered diminutive *Wievke* already implies the attribute *little*. Therefore, the adjective does not necessarily have to mean *little* and could mean something else. Since the pronunciation of the concerned word is described as “leaveuh”, “liva ”, or “levah”, the adjective *leve* seems to be a more likely candidate.

Thus, the complete expression, which is described as “leaveuh veefuh”, “liva vifa”, or “levah veefa”, would be ***leve Wievke*** [ˈleːfə ˈviːfkə].

(By the way, in East Frisian Low German, the letter *v* should be pronounced [f] rather than [v]. Hence, the locals are unhappy about the pronunciation of *Jever* in German beer commercials.)

Comment: Similar to the Afrikaans expression *liewe wyfie* (dear female).

Answer (score 2):

This is pretty interesting, because the "east-frisian" language almost doesn't exist anymore. I have been in North and Ost Friesland multiple times. So your grantmother was one of the last speaking east-frisians with possible german words / Platt.

Maybe I can support you because I do speak and write the westerlauwers-frisian language (+500.000 speakers). This language has the same "parent" language as east-frisian.

So the West-Frisian translation of "little wifey" is "lyts wiif". Which is in english: "Little wife". This is more the "rough not decently" sarcasm version for "little woman", which can be translated to the German version (as @Loong mention) to "Kleine Frau / Kleine Mädchen" (decently version).

Also if you look through history you'll see that the North en east Frisian language has been exchanged by the Lower Saxony language. Now adays known as "Platt" dialect. This dialect is also spoken in the Groningen Province in The Netherlands, with Dutch en West-Frisian influence. Also they are using the word "Wiifen" (womens | Frauen | Mädchen). There meaning is more like "Wicht" in the German language. But "Wicht" in the Dutch language is more like a swear word for a Girl / Women. As far i know, the word "wicht" is not used in the Frisian language.

If I look at the words: leaveuh, veefuh, liva vifa, or levah veefa. 
The official translation to westlauwers-frisian of "leaveuh, liva and levah is "Leave" (almost matches). Which means: sweatheart. The words: Veefuh, vifa, veefa. I cannot relate. In this case I comply with @Loong. I know that "Vifa" is a germantic lastname.

I am also using this word "leave(uh)" to my girlfriend. Like: "he leave hoe giet it mei dy". Which translates to: Hi Sweathearth, how are you going.

Basically as I look to my mother language: "Little wifey" (lyts wiif) is a sarcasm introduction for "He sweetheart" (he leave). Which indicates that your Grandmother really loves / likes you. We do the same.

Nice to know: to extend the dislaimer of @Loong. When you are going to Friesland (The Netherlands) do no use the [g] as a long [GGGG] like scraping your throat (Hollandisch people do). Make it sound like [guh]. Also do not use the [r] as a long [RRR], this will make you sound like a rich arrogant a**hole (Hollandisch people do). (west) Frisian people hate it.

Hopefully this information can extend your search for the right words!